# Autoit: controllers not working with background image

Tags: autoit

After adding an image in the background, the controllers on the page don't react anymore and I don't know how to resolve this.

Here is my code:

```
#Region ### START Koda GUI section ### Form=  

$TDPAGE = GUICreate("TD", 615, 441, 184, 116)
GUICtrlCreatePic(@ScriptDir & '\fond2.jpg', 0, 0, 0, 0)
$Label_titleTD= GUICtrlCreateLabel("TD", 233, 36, 91, 85)
GUICtrlSetFont(-1, 36, 800, 0, "My Lucky Penny") 
GUICtrlSetBkColor($Label_titreTD, $GUI_BKCOLOR_TRANSPARENT   
$FileTD = GUICtrlCreateButton("File", 136, 168, 75, 25)   
$QuitTD = GUICtrlCreateButton("Quit", 336, 168, 75, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

#EndRegion ### END Koda GUI section ###

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
       Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
                        Exit
      Case $FileTD
                        Run("Explorer.exe " & "O:\EPREUVE E6\COMPETENCES\TD")   
        Case $QuitTD
           Exit
            ExitLoop
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After creating the image I added:

```
GUICtrlSetState(-1, $GUI_DISABLE)
```

And it worked